# json string passed in url which is encoded by urlencode

Tags: php, json, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter 3.x.

User have this data : `%7B%5C%22uid%5C%22%3A%5C%221234%5C%22%2C%5C%22uname%5C%22%3A%5C%22kishor%5C%22%7D`

User send me the request and pass the data as parameter in url. The last parameter in url is nothing but the users data.

```
http://localhost/codeigniter/myproject/myfunction/%7B%5C%22uid%5C%22%3A%5C%221234%5C%22%2C%5C%22uname%5C%22%3A%5C%22kishor%5C%22%7D
```

The encoded data nothing but a json string which he want to encode and then send me the request. If I parse it using php then it yields this : `'{"uid":"1234","uname":"kishor"}'`

But it is not accepted in url, it gives me `Object not found!` error in browser.

> Object not found!
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>       Error 404

I tried changing `$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';`, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: I would recommend to convert the JSON in a query string URL. It will do the trick.

Comment: It is api and user have the data in this format, ```%7B%5C%22uid%5C%22%3A%5C%221234%5C%22%2C%5C%22uname%5C%22%3A%5C%22kishor%5C%22%7D```. Hence I need to accept the input as is and then process. But it is not working.

Comment: Then you have to make that API with POST method set that as string API parameter. Lets say, `user_data` and pass the entire JSON string to it. And you can easily get it in php and play with it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your CodeIgniter is set up properly and routing things correctly then I recommend sending the JSON as a `$_GET` parameter:

```
http://localhost/codeigniter/myproject/myfunction/?json=%7B%5C%22uid%5C%22%3A%5C%221234%5C%22%2C%5C%22uname%5C%22%3A%5C%22kishor%5C%22%7D
```

So in CodeIgniter, you should be able to simply:

```
json_decode( $this->input->get( 'json' ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the below way than you have to pass argument in function.

```
http://localhost/codeigniter/myproject/myfunction/%7B%5C%22uid%5C%22%3A%5C%221234%5C%22%2C%5C%22uname%5C%22%3A%5C%22kishor%5C%22%7D
```

like this

```
function myfunction($param = ''){ echo $params; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are passing is not a proper way. If you need to get and decode that value, use following way in your controller function

> i dont know which one is controller & function in your code, I guess `myproject` is a controller. So, i'm passing 3rd parameter Number 3 in `segment`

```
// it will return %7B%5C%22uid%5C%22%3A%5C%221234%5C%22%2C%5C%22uname%5C%22%3A%5C%22kishor%5C%22%7D
$json_value = $this->uri->segment(3); 
$json_value = (array) json_decode(stripslashes(urldecode($json_value)));

var_export($json_value);
```

**output**

```
array (
  'uid' => '1234',
  'uname' => 'kishor',
)
```